# Combine multiple fields from one class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class of the following types but I am unsure how to combine many to one. I have a master list called Assets which can contain the following:

```
public class Asset
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public string ValuationDate { get; set; }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public int OutstandingFinance { get; set; }
    public int FinanceAccountHolder { get; set; }
    public int FinanceMonthlyPayment { get; set; }
    public object FinanceEndDate { get; set; }
    public bool Home { get; set; }
    public int AssetType { get; set; }
    public object FixedPeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    public int ValuationSource { get; set; }
    public int Equity { get; set; }
    public bool IsSharedOwnership { get; set; }
    public object HousingAssociation { get; set; }
    public int HousingAssociationShareOfPropertyPercent { get; set; }
    public bool BeneficialInterest { get; set; }
    public object JointOwner1 { get; set; }
    public object JointOwner2 { get; set; }
    public object JointOwner3 { get; set; }
    public int RentalIncome { get; set; }
    public object AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public object PropertySecuredAgainstId { get; set; }
    public string FinanceCompany { get; set; }
}
```

I need to no how I would combine the following for example I need to popupulate say  Which would be classed as a car asset but I need to pull my data from another source but combine them into the single class.

Description 
CurrentValue 
Owner

But of course if i use the `List<Asset>` it will end up creating a new node for each section

```
public List<Asset> getallVechiclesForSlate()
{
    List<tbl_Vehicle> _vehicle = new List<tbl_Vehicle>();
    Asset _asset = new Asset(); 
    _vehicle = dal.GetAllVehiclesByCaseId(caseid);

    foreach (var vechicle in _vehicle)
    {
        CurrentFinance = dal.GetFinanceByVehicleId(vechicle.Vehicle_id);
        _asset.Description = vechicle.make + " " + vechicle.model;
        _asset.CurrentValue = (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(vechicle.valueOfVehicle));

        if (CurrentFinance.FinanceOutstanding == true)
        {
            _asset.OutstandingFinance = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _asset.OutstandingFinance = 1;
        }

        _asset.FinanceMonthlyPayment = (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(CurrentFinance.MonthlyCost)); 
    } 
}
```

Example of the json is as follows screen shot of how it is is here

https://snag.gy/DGiy3w.jpg

```
{
  "Id": "1ff540fa-664e-4d06-b972-e768e897f6ed",
  "LeadSourceId": "dcb14606-6abd-4bea-886c-c498f65c9e98",
  "Reference": "VB90590714",
  "FirstName": "Johnny",
  "MiddleName": null,
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Title": "Miss",
  "Gender": 2,
  "DateOfBirth": "1980-01-01T00:00:00",
  "Occupation": "Supervisor",
  "MaritalStatusTypeName": "Single",
  "ResidencyTypeName": "Renting",
  "ReasonForDifficultyTypeName": "Other",
  "ReasonForDifficultyDescription": "due to a reduction in hours. My children are staying in full time education for the time being. Not looking at Uni. Older child has a placement to go to after college so will be getting paid and she has already said that he will have to pay board. This will apply to the younger one when the time comes.",
  "HomePhoneNumber": "01234567891",
  "WorkPhoneNumber": "01234567891",
  "MobilePhoneNumber": "01234567891",
  "Email": "",
  "Created": "2016-10-11T08:50:20.8337591+01:00",
  "TotalUnsecuredDebtLevel": 4999.0,
  "JobStartDate": "2016-01-01T00:00:00",
  "HaveBankAccount": true,
  "BanksWith": "Halifax Plc",
  "SalaryPaymentFrequency": 1,
  "LivingWithPartner": false,
  "IsJoint": false,
  "PartnerFirstName": "Joan",
  "PartnerLastName": "Smith",
  "PartnerDob": "1970-02-02T00:00:00",
  "PartnerOccupation": null,
  "PartnerEmploymentStatus": 0,
  "PartnerTitle": "",
  "PartnerMobilePhone": "01234567891",
  "PartnerEmail": "phil.carney@drspclaims.co.uk",
  "PartnerGender": 0,
  "PartnerJobStartDate": null,
  "PartnerNiNumber": "CD123456A",
  "PartnerSalaryPaymentFrequency": 1,
  "MainAddress": {
    "AddressOne": "11040 Park Road",
    "AddressTwo": "Timperley",
    "AddressThree": "Cheshire",
    "Postcode": "WA15 1AB"
  },
  "CorrespondenceAddress": {
    "AddressOne": "11040 Park Road",
    "AddressTwo": "Timperley",
    "AddressThree": "Cheshire",
    "Postcode": "WA15 1AB"
  },
  "EmploymentStatus": 0,
  "NiNumber": "AB123456A",
  "Debts": [{
    "DebtTypeName": "Other",
    "AmountOwed": 2609.87,
    "MonthlyPayment": 1.0,
    "DebtResponsibility": 1,
    "CreditorName": "North Somerset Council",
    "AccountNumber": "5016522727",
    "DebtStatus": "1 Month in arrears",
    "Documents": []
  }, {
    "DebtTypeName": "Other",
    "AmountOwed": 1045.63,
    "MonthlyPayment": 1.0,
    "DebtResponsibility": 1,
    "CreditorName": "North Somerset Council",
    "AccountNumber": "90517291",
    "DebtStatus": "1 Month in arrears",
    "Documents": []
  }, {
    "DebtTypeName": "Other",
    "AmountOwed": 1031.61,
    "MonthlyPayment": 109.00,
    "DebtResponsibility": 1,
    "CreditorName": "Argos Card Services",
    "AccountNumber": "6335409910455368986",
    "DebtStatus": "1 Month in arrears",
    "Documents": []
  }],
  "Dependants": [{
    "Dob": "1999-09-17T00:00:00",
    "Name": "Bill",
    "LivesWith": 0
  }, {
    "Dob": "1998-03-13T00:00:00",
    "Name": "Bill",
    "LivesWith": 0
  }],
  "Documents": [],
  "Incomes": [{
    "IncomeTypeName": "Child Benefit",
    "Frequency": 2,
    "Amount": 34
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Income from lodger",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Child Maintenance",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Working Tax Credit",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 197
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Income Support",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Salary",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 910
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Benefits",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Housing Benefit",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "State Pension",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Disability Living Allowance",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Self Employment",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Child Tax Credit",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 388
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Occupational Pension",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Personal Pension",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Job Seekers Allowance",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Employment Support Allowance",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Incapacity Benefit",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Unspecified",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Carers Allowance",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }, {
    "IncomeTypeName": "Partners Salary",
    "Frequency": 1,
    "Amount": 1
  }],
  "Expenditures": [{
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Health",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Sundries & Emergencies",
    "AmountMonthly": 37
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Home Help",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Charity",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Business Costs",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Smoking",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Ground Rent",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Applicant2 IVA Contribution",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Electricity",
    "AmountMonthly": 60
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Coal",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Arrears (Accommodation)",
    "AmountMonthly": 59
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Endowments",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Children's Activities",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Life",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Sport, Hobbies & Entertainment",
    "AmountMonthly": 44
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Internet",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "TV Package",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Work Meals",
    "AmountMonthly": 42
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Gas",
    "AmountMonthly": 60
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Rent",
    "AmountMonthly": 506
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Contents",
    "AmountMonthly": 9
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Water",
    "AmountMonthly": 47
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Arrears (Household Bills)",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "School Meals",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "TV Licence",
    "AmountMonthly": 12
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Repairs & Servicing",
    "AmountMonthly": 15
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Income Protection",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Other (Insurance)",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Pets, Pet Food & Insurance",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Child Maintenance",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Vehicle Tax",
    "AmountMonthly": 10
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Non Dependent Child Allowance",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "School Trips & Activities",
    "AmountMonthly": 14
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "School Fees & Expenses",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Boiler",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Clothing & Footwear",
    "AmountMonthly": 36
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Breakdown Cover",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Other (Household Bills)",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Child Care",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Buildings",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Professional Fees",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Vehicle Maintenance",
    "AmountMonthly": 20
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Partner Commitments",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "CCJ",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Appliance Rental",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Mortgage Protection",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Service Charge",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Telephone inc. Mobile",
    "AmountMonthly": 20
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Laundry & Dry Cleaning",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Educational Costs",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Waste Collection",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Heating Oil",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "TV Rental",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Other (Accommodation)",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Dentist / Opticians",
    "AmountMonthly": 13
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Secured Homes",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Medicines / Prescriptions",
    "AmountMonthly": 12
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Other (Miscellaneous)",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Sky Insurance Plan",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Storage Fees",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Mobile Phone",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Public Transport",
    "AmountMonthly": 40
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Newspapers & Magazines",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Kit",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Hair",
    "AmountMonthly": 26
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Fuel & Parking",
    "AmountMonthly": 55
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Pocket Money",
    "AmountMonthly": 24
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Food, Toiletries & Cleaning",
    "AmountMonthly": 270
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Gym",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Board",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Credit Union",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Vehicle Finance",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Hire Purchase",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Other (Travel)",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Vehicle Insurance",
    "AmountMonthly": 40
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "Council Tax",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }, {
    "ExpenditureTypeName": "DLA",
    "AmountMonthly": 1
  }],
  "Notes": [],
  "Assets": [{
    "Id": "59426e26-22c8-4a61-8cf2-26f1f901b030",
    "Description": "Mini Cooper",
    "CurrentValue": 4000,
    "ValuationDate": "2016-08-18T00:00:00",
    "Owner": 1,
    "OutstandingFinance": 0,
    "FinanceAccountHolder": 1,
    "FinanceMonthlyPayment": 0,
    "FinanceEndDate": null,
    "Home": false,
    "AssetType": 0,
    "FixedPeriodEndDate": null,
    "ValuationSource": 0,
    "Equity": 4000,
    "IsSharedOwnership": false,
    "HousingAssociation": null,
    "HousingAssociationShareOfPropertyPercent": 0,
    "BeneficialInterest": false,
    "JointOwner1": null,
    "JointOwner2": null,
    "JointOwner3": null,
    "RentalIncome": 0,
    "AccountNumber": null,
    "PropertySecuredAgainstId": null,
    "FinanceCompany": ""
  }]
}
```

**Edit 2**
So Would i be right in saying that this would be the approach I would take to ensure this.

```
public class Asset : carAsset
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
}

public class carAsset
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public string ValuationDate { get; set; }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public int OutstandingFinance { get; set; }
    public int FinanceAccountHolder { get; set; }
    public int FinanceMonthlyPayment { get; set; }
    public object FinanceEndDate { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }    
}
```

I might be over complication this when i say two assets there will always be the main asset node , their be mutiple assets below that ie 1,2,3 with the same values of the full asset class within that but i need to combine the class.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a good time to learn about inheritance `CarAsset` and `BaseAsset` for example.

Comment: @Sayse yes I was thinking that approach but its more how do i make sure there is one asset node will this allow that as well then

Comment: @Sayse can you see my edit in edit 2 i think im over complicating this